# C# Updating a value in a list of objects is updating other values too

Tags: c#, list, copy

I was working on a simple turn based RPG game.  I was working on a battle system.  I had it working with 1 enemy, and wanted to update it to work on multiple enemies.  I have it spawning multiple enemies, but I am having issues targeting them.

Basically, the enemies are stored in a list called actualEnemies.  The enemies are generated at run time, and there can be between 1-3.  A label is generated to display the enemy name, and the enemy is selected by double clicking on it.

The issue seems to be in the naming of the enemy's.  They have a property called characterName to identify an enemy.  The problem is, there can be 2 or more of the same type of character (for example, 3x Goblin).  So in the code where the enemies are generated, I was wanting to add a 1 to the characterName if there already is one in the list.  The idea is to give each enemy a unique name.

The problem is, when I try this, it changes the values of all of the enemies of the same name, and this is screwing with everything.  Here is the relevant section of code:

```
if (EnemyExists(e)) {
    e.characterName += c.ToString();                            
}
```

c is simply a counter that is being used, to let me know if it is enemy 1, 2 or 3.

The EnemyExists function is as follows:

```
public bool EnemyExists(Enemy e) {
    bool exists = false;
    int eCount = 0;

    foreach (Enemy en in actualEnemies) {
        if (en.characterName == e.characterName) {
            eCount++;
        }
    }

    if (eCount > 1) {
        exists = true;
    }

    return exists;
}
```

Just to note, the enemies all start off with a default name.  For this example I am working on, there are only 2 kinds of enemy.  The game picks a random number between 1-3, to decide how many enemies there are.  Each enemy will be one of the 2 pre defined enemies, picked at random again.  This is why I just want to add a number to the end of a name that is already present.

I suspect it has something to do with how I am creating the list of enemies:

```
public void CreateActualEnemies() {
    int r;
    int potEnemyNum = potentialEnemies.Count;         
    int numEnemies;
    Random rand = new Random();
    numEnemies = rand.Next(1, 4 );

    for (int i = 0; i < numEnemies; i++) {
        r = rand.Next(0,potEnemyNum);
        Enemy ene = new Enemy();
        ene = potentialEnemies.ElementAt(r);
        actualEnemies.Add(ene);
    }

    DisplayEnemyDetails();
}
```

When I add to actualEnemies, am I just pointing to an address in potentialEnemies, so even though I am instantiating a new Enemy, each one, if it has the same name, points to the same place?  Do I need to properly copy the object?

It is late, I am tired, but I feel like I am getting closer, any help would be great, thanks.

EDIT:

Enemy Class:

```
public class Enemy:Character {
    public int xpGiven { get; set; }
    public LootTable lootTable { get; set; }
    public int goldDropped { get; set; }
    public bool alive { get; set; }
    public NamedTimer timer { get; set; }

    public Enemy() {
        alive = true;
        xpGiven = 10;
        lootTable = new LootTable();
        goldDropped = 10;
        timer = new NamedTimer();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide class definition of `Enemy`

Comment: public class Enemy:Character 
    {
        public int xpGiven { get; set; }
            public LootTable lootTable { get; set; }
        public int goldDropped { get; set; }
        public bool alive { get; set; }
        public NamedTimer timer { get; set; }
        public Enemy()
        {
            alive = true;
            xpGiven = 10;
            lootTable = new LootTable();
            goldDropped = 10;
            timer = new NamedTimer();            
        }
  
    }

Comment: Just edit it into your original question, with the code tag.

Comment: Done, sorry.  Forgot I could edit the original :p

Answer (score 2):

Breaking down your question:

> When I add to actualEnemies, am I just pointing to an address in potentialEnemies, so even though I am instantiating a new Enemy, each one, if it has the same name, points to the same place?

By doing

```
Enemy ene = new Enemy();
```

You are essentialy creating a new pointer in memory with a "blank" valued-reference.
However, since you did

```
ene = potentialEnemies.ElementAt(r);
```

You overwrote it with the reference to the element in the list. So whatever changes you do the `ene` object will reflect the item in the list.

If you want to segregate said changes, try using a [`MemberwiseClone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx).

From the example given at MSDN:

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Age;
    public string Name;
    public IdInfo IdInfo;

    public Person ShallowCopy()
    {
       return (Person) this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public Person DeepCopy()
    {
       Person other = (Person) this.MemberwiseClone();
       other.IdInfo = new IdInfo(IdInfo.IdNumber);
       other.Name = String.Copy(Name);
       return other;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I added a shallow copy method and used it.  Worked a treat.

Comment: If that answer helped, vote it up and mark it as *the* answer :) Glad to have helped.

Comment: @rm46, you may want to use something similar to the `DeepCopy()` method, because some of the properties of class `Enemy` appear to be reference types, like `lootTable` and `timer`. Your newly created `Enemy`, if you've something implemented similar to `ShallowCopy()`, will end up referring to the same `lootTable` and `timer` objects. This could potentially lead to new issues similar to your current issue later on.

Answer (score 0):

1: Property names should start with a capital letter in C#. I.e. `public int xpGiven { get; set; }` should be `public int XpGiven { get; set; }`. If it's a class variable (no get or set defined), you start with a lower case letter. To more easily identify class variables from local variables, programmers typically start them with a _, although this is not mandatory.

2: When doing `==`, please be aware `enemyA == enemya` will return false. Use `enemyA.Equals(enemya, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` to ignore capital differences.

3:

```
public void CreateActualEnemies()
    {
        int r;
        int potEnemyNum = potentialEnemies.Count;         
        int numEnemies;
        Random rand = new Random();
        numEnemies = rand.Next(1, 4 );
        for (int i = 0; i < numEnemies; i++)
        {
            r = rand.Next(0,potEnemyNum);
            Enemy ene = new Enemy();
            ene = potentialEnemies.ElementAt(r);
            actualEnemies.Add(ene);
        }
        DisplayEnemyDetails();
    }
```

should be:

```
public void CreateActualEnemies()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int numEnemies = rand.Next(1, 4 );

        for (int i = 0; i < numEnemies; i++)
        {
            Enemy ene = new Enemy();
            ene.characterName = "" + ene.GetType().Name + " " + i; // or something similar to give the ene a unique name.
            actualEnemies.Add(ene);
        }
        DisplayEnemyDetails();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The problem I have now with that is that the enemies are all at a default state, as opposed to selecting from a pre defined list.  Is there a way to take a copy of an object from one list, add it to another, but it is a new object, no longer holding a reference to the original list?

Comment: 1. That's not mandatory: There are as many naming conventions as there are ice cream flavors. There is no correct one.
2. If both types are strings, then there is _absolutely_ no reason not to use `==`
3. Mind explaining the correction?

Comment: @rm46 typically no. You can do `var ene = new Enemy() { characterName = actualEnemies[i].characterName, level = otherEnemy.level }` and in that way set all properties, based on another enemey's properties. Or you can use reflection to go over all properties and copy their value. What you can't do is say `ene = otherEne`, as this will point `ene` to the other object.

Comment: @Chrotenise Reflection is not necessary. MemberwiseClones will do that just fine.

Comment: @EricWu 1. is straight out of the MSDN guidelines for coding in C#. Although no one will shoot you for not following it, I would really suggest adhering to these guidelines when learning to program and only divert from them if your company demands it in their coding convention. 2. completely messed up there (I think it's time for bed). I meant to say that you should use Equals() to avoid capitalization mistakes